# Hoping to add a series of dates thru an API call using a for loop

Tags: python, html, pandas, api, for-loop

Problem: when I run the snippet below I get the following error: "URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer>."

When I run the same snippet with a date range instead of a variable it works.

I have a list of dates that I need to pass through an API call.

Here is the process to replicate

1. create the data frame for the date ranges I need [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg6NE.png)
2. Then run a loop to get the call for all the date ranges in the first dataframe [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8GIj.png)

python snippet

```
earnings_info = []
for earnings_api in all_earnings['earnings_api']:
    web_add = earnings_api
    ticker_hist_earnings = pd.read_json(web_add)
    earnings_info.append(ticker_hist_earnings)
    sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for this. The most occurring one is the API recognized your call as a bot call and block your connection.
If you are using pandas inbuild URL call you have to re write it to get from request library and include browser headers.

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'})
```

and after getting all the data you can append those data into pandas df.

Comment: interesting now getting Error 429: Too Many Requests

Comment: Can you please add a delay in-between the request calls

Comment: Currently I'm adding sleep(10) to the end of the loop: import requests
`earnings_info = []

for earnings_api in all_earnings['earnings_api']:
    web_add = earnings_api
    response = requests.get(web_add, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'})
    ticker_hist_earnings = pd.read_json(web_add)
    earnings_info.append(ticker_hist_earnings)
    sleep(10)`

Comment: Hi you haven't replaced the read_json with response. where do you make the request call ? Please replace the ticker_hist_earnings code line with following line
ticker_hist_earnings = pd.read_json(response.json())

Comment: This gives me an 'invalid path' error. Usually all I need to do to make the call is `web_add = "https://api.earningscalendar.net/confirmed_earnings?from_date=2021-05-22&to_date=2021-05-30&api_key=xx"
e_calendar = pd.read_json(web_add)` and this gives me the results

Comment: Hi Yes now i get it. pd.read_json will send a request internally and it causes the problem in the beginning. You are getting results for one request call that's true. Since you need to send a batch of requests you have to switch to request response architecture. Otherwise API thinks that you are a bot. Please dont use read_json. Instead use this 
`from pandas import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(dresponse.json())` this will get all the data to pandas df

Comment: This worked. Incredible. Thank you so much. Guys like you truly hold the world together. Thank you and bless you.

Comment: Hi, You are welcome and Thank you very much for the kind words. Can you please do me a favor and upvote my answer too.